# I tried to rename all colons to underscores via linux terminal, it went tits up and I can't see the files anymore, help greatly appreciated

Tags: linux

I used the following:

```
find /path/to/files -name '*:*' -exec rename ':' '_' {} +
```

(so...)

```
find /media/(the rest of the dir)/archive/ -name '*:*' -exec rename ':' '_' {} +
```

And now all of the files have vanished, but now I have plugged the external HD into windows, it still recognises 2.xGB of data, but cannot see any files inside the folders.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as the data is vital!

Edit: Here is the output of `ls -lsa`:

```
0 drwx ------ 1 dc adm    0 <date> . 
0 drwx ------ 1 dc adm    0 <date> . 
0 drwx ------ 1 dc adm    0 <date> 2011 
4 drwx ------ 1 dc adm 4096 <date> 2012
```

Comment: Huh? What? Why?

Comment: The files wouldn't open in windows with the colon. I was trying to mass-rename to get rid of the colon and replace it with an underscore, so I could open them in windows.

Comment: In the other OS (Assuming Linux?) what does "ls -lsa" show in the archive directory?

Comment: Can you browse the files with Midnight Commander?

Comment: 0 drwx ------ 1 dc adm 0 <date> .
0 drwx ------ 1 dc adm 0 <date> .
0 drwx ------ 1 dc adm 0 <date> 2011
4 drwx ------ 1 dc adm 4096 <date> 2012

Comment: I think that's a first 'tits-up' in a SF question title.

Comment: First time for everything. I'm relatively new to command line linux, can someone explain what I screwed up in the find command?

Comment: @user151000, can you just restore from your backups?

Comment: Unfortunately this was done prior to a backup :(

Comment: I'd just like to know specifically what I have done. Have I renamed/deleted/other? :s

Comment: Try actually looking in the `2011` and `2012` directories to see what's in them.

Comment: According to windows, nothing, other than the folder listings :(

Comment: From the `rename` man page, "*Always make a backup before running the command*".

Comment: This is not a command...no... more like minefield courtesy of Bill Gates. :P

Comment: David, will keep this mind for the future! :P

Comment: Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.